# PHP concatenate to variable

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, buddypress

I have the following function that sends a message to selected users

```
function send_msg($user_id, $title, $message){
$args = array( 'recipients' => $user_id, 'sender_id' => bp_loggedin_user_id(), 'subject' => $title, 'content' => $message );
$thread_id = messages_new_message1( $args );
messages_delete_thread($thread_id,bp_loggedin_user_id());
}
```

This is invoked by the following code that posts the form

```
// Get data from form
    $body_input=isset($_POST['body_input'])?$_POST['body_input']:'';
    $subject_input=isset($_POST['subject_input'])?$_POST['subject_input']:'';

// Loop sending a message for each recipient
foreach(array_column($user_ids, 'user_id') as $user_N) {
    send_msg($user_N, $body_input, $subject_input);    
}
```

I want to edit the subject/title and message body before `send_msg`

I have tried

```
$args = array( 'recipients' => $user_id, 'sender_id' => bp_loggedin_user_id(), 'subject' => $title.'some text', 'content' => $message );
```

which does work but when I try

```
$args = array( 'recipients' => $user_id, 'sender_id' => bp_loggedin_user_id(), 'subject' => $title.'some text', 'content' => $message.'some text' );
```

It sends the message twice, one with `title` and `body` and another with `title.what_I_append` and `body.what_I_append`

I have also tried this way but this does not post

```
$body_input=isset($_POST['body_input'])?$_POST['body_input']:''.'some text to append';
```

How can I correctly concatenate to the variables used for subject and body?

Comment: Where are you calling send_msg()? Just before you call to this append your data to $subject, $message. Then pass through the already appended values.

Comment: @JParkinson1991 Would that be like `$body_input=isset($_POST['body_input'])?$_POST['body_input']:'';` then `$body_input = $body_input.'some text'`?

Comment: @JParkinson1991 Also, another answered then deleted `'content' => "{$message}some text"` which sends one message but REPLACES the message input with 'some text'

Comment: Yes whereever you want to call it. I would jsut recommend calling it before send_msg(). This function should not care about what content it is sending, its reponsibility should be to send the message only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick answer to follow my comments:

I would recommend send_msg() focus's only on sending the message.

Therefore append to the subject and body prior to sending these values to send_msg() function.

```
<?php

//Personally i wouldnt append to an empty value, your choice.
$subject = isset($_POST['subject_input']) 
    ? $_POST['subject_input'].' appended text'
    : ''
$body= isset($_POST['body_input']) 
    ? $_POST['body_input'].' appended text' 
    : '';

send_msg($user_id, $title, $body);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How could I do something like `...POST['subject_input'].$appendText`, the idea being to have $appendText = 'whatever';` just above that - edit: that works great, it wasnt when I commented as I didn't have `<?php`

Comment: Just do as youve done. Store what to append in a variable and append a variable :)